# Creating Zend_Form elements from row html

Tags: html, zend-framework, zend-form, html-helper

I am having an issue with Zend_Form and your help will be appreciated. 
in fact I have a class to generate categories as options

```
$categories = My_Util_Category::toHtmlSelect();//for simplicity I removed other lines
```

this code generates

```
<select> 
 <option > root</option> 
 <option> root / children</option> 
 </select>
```

On another hand, I use Zend_Form form to edit categories. The code looks like:

```
$form = My_Form_Category( $data, $selectElements = array() );
```

which outputs a form, text field, a select box for parent categories and a submit button.

How can I get 'select element' from **$form**, and replace it with row html 'select' generated with **$categories**

any help, or link will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I changed the drop down list, and instead of

```
$categories = My_Util_Category::toHtmlSelect();
```

I have

```
$categoryList = My_Util_Category::getCategoryList();
```

which returns an array and pass returned array to the form constructor as

```
$form = My_Form_Category( $data, $categoryList );
```

Hope that it will help some body else.